# Getting the name of the process, that corresponds to the active window

Tags: python, window-manager, process

How can it be done using Python in Ubuntu?

Comment: You should ask on StackOverflow. There are some smart py people over there.

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983946/get-active-window-title-in-x

Comment: Did you mean the *pid* or the process' *name*? Also, what is exactly the purpose? Process *name*, the *WM_CLASS* and the command to call the application are possibly not the same. (e.g. `libreoffice` <> `soffice.bin` etc)

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

```py
import subprocess

pid = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowpid"]).decode("utf-8").strip()

print(pid)
```

but you'd need to install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

#### Get the name of the WM_CLASS

We can even surpass the pid:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

w_id = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"]).decode("utf-8")
name = subprocess.check_output(["xprop", "-id", w_id, "WM_CLASS"]).decode("utf-8").strip()

print(name)
```

Mind though that the WM_CLASS often, but not necessarily always is the process *name*.

Comment: I borrowed the 'getactivewindow' part of your answer as an expansion upon my `psutil` suggestion.  Sorry, but I hope you don't mind, I credited you in the answer a bit :)

Comment: i need small help, i want my python code to do something whenever the active window change, one way of doing it is using infinite while loop . but there must be some better way of doing it. how can i do it. how do i keep my python code alive while listening to if active window is changed?.

Comment: @AayushNeupane on X, or Wayland?

Comment: @JacobVlijm on X

Comment: @AayushNeupane Ah, right. Please ask a question, I (or anyone else) will answer. I think we shouldn't post it on this question. Please ping me if you do.

Comment: actually i have asked this question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729754/execute-python-code-if-active-window-change-in-linux?noredirect=1#comment117960716_66729754 please consider answering it there

Comment: @AayushNeupane here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66741216/1391444

Answer (score 3):

`psutil` seems to be what you might want.

What's unclear in your question is whether you want the executable name or the window title.  However, if you're after the executable process's name, you can do it with `psutil` and some other functions.

First, install `psutil` with `pip` (Python 2) or `pip3` (Python 3).  If the command isn't found then install the `python-pip` or `python3-pip` packages depending on which Python version you're working with:

```
# Python 2
sudo pip install psutil

# Python 3
sudo pip3 install psutil
```

Next, we can use `psutil` in any given Python script, and pass a PID.  This is an example of what it can do, by running `python3` in the command line, working with the interactive Python 3 shell, and getting that process's information using Python code right on the Python shell:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> import os
>>> os.getpid()
6284
>>> p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> p.name()
'python3'
>>> p.exe()
'/usr/bin/python3.5'
>>> p.cmdline()
['python3']
>>>
```

As you can see you can get different information from the system about the process on both Windows or Linux with these utilities, though you still need to install the Python package first.

---

***EDIT***

We can also chain this with [Jacob Vlijm](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob-vlijm)'s answer here too, to get the PID and pass it into `psutil` (Note that I shorten 'subprocess' to 'sp' in my import, but it's still the `subprocess` module):

```py
import psutil
import subprocess as sp

p = psutil.Process(int(sp.check_output(["xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowpid"]).decode("utf-8").strip()))
```

... and then continue to use `psutil` to extract specific data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import wnck
screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
window = screen.get_active_window()
pid = window.get_pid()
```

Comment: This gets the ID of the process, but not the process' name. If you know the process ID, however, you could then open the System Monitor and match the ID to the process name in the table under the "Processes" tab.